# How to make my model as DRY as possible (identical table joins and field selections)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, model, dry

In my models I usually have at least 2 'get' routines `$model->get_one()` and `$model->get_where()` and my models often extend a `version_model` which handles db record versions and have routines like `get_record_history()`.

All of these routines select the same database fields and do the same table joins. So to make the joins DRY I have a routine defined in each model `$model->create_joins()` which is then used by `$model->get()` and the others mentioned above.

I'm thinking of also adding `$model->select_fields()` to make the field selection DRY as well but I thought I'd post here and see how other people handle this or if there is a better method altogether?

**Edit:** The question: is there a better method than the one described above for not repeating table joins in routines that select the same data with different criteria in my model. Is this something that a library like PDO handles?

Comment: Please formulate a concrete question. I do understand you want to know something but the question remains what?

Comment: @hakre apologies for the vague question - I have a working solution I just want suggestions of maybe a better way to achieve the same thing. Not every question has to be 'How do I select this element in jquery' with a one line answer - I can look at the documentation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rule of thumb about this called [Rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28programming%29), introduced by Martin Fowler and attributed to Don Roberts. From wikipedia:

> It states that the code can be copied once, but that when the same code is replicated three times, it should be extracted into a new procedure.

It's easy to get lost while applying the DRY principle, [abstracting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_principle_%28computer_programming%29) everything you can find,  resulting in over-complex application.

When doing abstraction to apply DRY, it's a good idea to think about cost/benefit ratio.

Abstracting common logic takes time, and makes the code more complex(in a way). But as a result, you get cleaner code.

If you are working on a quick fix that won't need maintenance, just copy paste it and get over with it. But if you are building a complex application that needs to be maintained, try to do the necessary abstraction, as it will save you more time in future probably.

For further reading:

[You ain't gonna need it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Ain%27t_Gonna_Need_It)

[KISS principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: If you do a fix that does not need maintenance, why do you do the fix at all?

Comment: I mean it for small problems that requires quick solutions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd say as well that to fix a typo in some text (or something similar to that) is not the sort of problem this question is about.

Comment: @HakanDeryal Many thanks for your answer - just the pointers I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

DRY is for design as well, but you write that your models sometimes extends from some class that cares about versioning.

Probably you should move everything out of the models that deals with persistance and versioning, so you can create other objects that can take care of that, so your code is more DRY.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean here - version_model is a single model that any model that requires record versioning can extend. Verion_model will then automatically create a timestamped table and log changes when $model->update() is called. There arn't multiple version models, what is not DRY about that?

Comment: Inside your application you have a model, then you have a model that also cares about versioning. That's not DRY, the model part is repeated.

Comment: This is how a lot of MVC frameworks are implemented, with models extending some base model. If I do what you suggest and create objects to handle the versioning then I end up having to bastardize my models with calls to some versioning object, which if I forget to do then my table won't be versioned. With my method, if I suddenly decide I want versioning on a table I simply change a single line of code (... extends Version_model) and use all my usual methods, like $model->delete(), $model->update() and the versioning is automatically handled.

Comment: Yes, your model has basically two responsibilities (while a class should only have one): Being the model (e.g. a plain old PHP object that has methods and members) and then to store that into the persistence layer. You asked about DRY, and in my eyes that is not DRY. And you don't need to bastardize your models, the persistence layer can take care of that, not the models (!).

Comment: right, are you saying that my database abstraction object should be handling the versioning, not the model? If so, then the reason I've done it this way round is because codeigniter doesn't allow extension of the db class

Comment: well, you can add your own classes next to the ones of codeigniter, especially for models and persistence which has the benefit that you won't too much be influenced by the design of codeigniter. And the persistence layer does not extend a db class but just uses one to talk to the database. Maybe a good hint for you is not to think too much about "extend".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9691/discussion-between-rgvcorley-and-hakre)